# Need to set authorization for a single table inside keyspace

Tags: authentication, cassandra, authorization

I am using cassandra 3.11.4 and CQL spec 3.4.4 
All of my node microservices using cassandra do not use any kind of authentication. The authenticator field inside the cassandra yaml is currently set to authenticator: AllowAllAuthenticator

The issue is that I want to create authorization with roles attached to it for a single table inside my keyspace, while not requiring anything as such for other tables in the keyspace.

Is something like this possible? As I can check, my services using express cassandra start throwing error as soon as I change the authenticator: PasswordAuthenticator.

In my production, I would not want that since that will break my working services and they will start throwing error asking for auth info in the connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<opinion>
```

Running an unsecured Cassandra cluster is a terrible, **terrible** idea.  Especially one used by multiple services or applications.

```
</opinion>
```

Here's what I would do:

1. Recreate the "secure" table to its own keyspace.  Keeping it in the original keyspace makes it easier to isolate and apply security.
2. Come up with a username and password for all services to use.  Ex: `shareduser`/`blahblahblah`
3. Set your services to use the shared user and its password.  The Cassandra drivers can send credentials along with auth disabled on the cluster...it simply ignores them.
4. Turn on Authentication and Authorization on one node, and restart.  Your services will continue to connect through the remaining, insecure nodes.
5. Authenticate to the secure node with cqlsh.  Alter the replication of the `system_auth` keyspace to replicate to at least 3 nodes in each DC.  Then create both the shared user and the secured user.
6. Grant the secure user access to the required table in its new keyspace.  Grant the shared user access to the original keyspace.

Ex:

```
GRANT ALL PERMISSIONS ON keyspace2.securetable TO secureuser;

GRANT ALL ON KEYSPACE keyspace1 TO shareduser;
```

7. Verify that the users can access the required tables.
8. Turn on Authentication and Authorization on the remaining nodes, and restart Cassandra on them.

These steps should allow your existing services should continue to work without issue.